# Is there a Google reCAPTCHA plugin available for Redmine version 5.0.5?

Tags: recaptcha, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have recently upgraded **Redmine** from version **3.4.6 to 5.0.5**. The Google reCAPTCHA plugin we were using earlier is no longer supported, as it relies on deprecated requirements and did not install properly in the new version.

I attempted to install the older plugin we were using, but it resulted in an error due to deprecated requirements. Additionally, I have searched the Redmine plugin repositories, but I could not find any Google reCAPTCHA plugin that is compatible with version 5.0.5. So, could anyone provide a Google reCAPTCHA plugin that is compatible with version 5.0.5?

Answer (score 0):

There's an updated version of the plugin that you probably had been using here https://github.com/cdwertmann/recaptcha (it mentions being working at least until 5.0.4)